# Mongoose updating subdocument array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

**I want to update rooms subdocument which is in Property document, but I get this error:**

> MongoServerError: Updating the path 'rooms.$.updatedAt' would create a
> conflict at 'rooms.$'

**Error which i got in postman:**

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 40,
    "codeName": "ConflictingUpdateOperators",
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": {
            "$timestamp": "7137698220989218823"
        },
        "signature": {
            "hash": "34spx6E0zZFa5bVYFSL2JyjFszQ=",
            "keyId": {
                "low": 2,
                "high": 1646669662,
                "unsigned": false
            }
        }
    },
    "operationTime": {
        "$timestamp": "7137698220989218823"
    }
}
```

**My property model:**

```
import { IReview, ReviewSchema } from './reviews.model'
import { IRoom, RoomSchema } from './room.model'

type TCheapestRoom = {
    roomType: string
    bedType: string
    lastPrice: number
    actualPrice: number
}

export interface IProperty {
    propertyType: string
    name: string
    description: string
    city: string
    photos: [string]
    cheapestRoom: TCheapestRoom
    adress: string
    distance: number
    cancellationPolicy: string
    meals: string
    funThingsToDo: [string]
    accessibility: [string]
    rooms: IRoom[]
    reviews: IReview[]
}

interface IPropertyDocument extends IProperty, Document {
    createdAt: Date
    updatedAt: Date
    // rooms: Types.Array<IRoom>
}

const PropertySchema = new Schema<IPropertyDocument>(
    {
        propertyType: { type: String, required: true },
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        city: { type: String, required: true },
        photos: { type: [String] },
        cheapestRoom: {
            roomType: { type: String },
            bedType: { type: String },
            lastPrice: { type: Number },
            actualPrice: { type: Number },
        },
        adress: { type: String, required: true },
        distance: { type: Number, required: true },
        cancellationPolicy: { type: String, required: true },
        meals: { type: String, required: true },
        funThingsToDo: { type: [String] },
        accessibility: { type: [String] },
        rooms: [RoomSchema],
        reviews: [ReviewSchema],
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)

const PropertyModel = model<IPropertyDocument>('Property', PropertySchema)
export default PropertyModel
```

**Subdocument room model:**

```
export interface IRoom {
    roomType: string
    bedTypes: [string]
    roomFacilities: [string]
    sleeps: number
    lastPrice: number
    actualPrice: number
    cancellation: string
    payment: string
    breakfast: string
    unavailableDates: [Date]
}

export interface IRoomDocument extends IRoom, Document {
    createdAt: Date
    updatedAt: Date
}

export const RoomSchema = new Schema<IRoomDocument>(
    {
        roomType: { type: String, required: true },
        bedTypes: { type: [String], required: true },
        roomFacilities: { type: [String], required: true },
        sleeps: { type: Number, required: true, default: 2 },
        lastPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
        actualPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
        cancellation: { type: String, required: true },
        payment: { type: String, required: true },
        breakfast: { type: String, required: true },
        unavailableDates: { type: [Date] },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)

const RoomModel = model<IRoomDocument>('Room', RoomSchema)
export default RoomModel
```

**room controller:**

```
import PropertyModel from '../models/property.model'
import RoomModel from '../models/room.model'
const updateRoom = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const updatedProperty = await PropertyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.params.propertyId, 'rooms._id': req.params.roomId },
            {
                $set: { 'rooms.$': req.body },
            },
            {
                new: true,
            }
        )
        res.status(201).json(updatedProperty)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).json(error)
    }
}

export { addNewRoom, deleteRoom, updateRoom }
```

I want to be able updating my subdocuments, in this case rooms using property id and room id.
How can i update this subdocument ?

Comment: Is that the proper syntax for [`Model.findByIdAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate)?

Comment: Oh you are right, I have to use findOneAndUpdate. I chahged it, but problem appears as before.

Comment: I would be better if you edit your question to represent the exact issue.  E.g., change your code to what you are trying and describe the effect, or lack of effect.

Comment: I have main Property Document (Schema) and subdocument Rooms, which is an array of room objects. I want to update single room in Property, by room and property id. When I try to do this I get an error which I show abow.

Comment: Also I get this error in vscode when i console log error, **Updating the path 'rooms.$.updatedAt' would create a conflict at 'rooms.$'**